# Google Tag Manager Trigger on "Click Element" not workin for contains or CSS Selector?

Tags: google-tag-manager, eventtrigger, velo

How do I set up my trigger to fire on this "Click Element" shown in the image? I have tried a wide range of contains as well as a matches CSS selector. This is for an Audio Player on a Wix website. It's the same Click Element for pause and play, so I'm only going to have to tag record once per page visit. However, I can't get the trigger to fire. No other variables are unique to their Audio Player. If I need a custom variable, what would that look like? Thanks!

[GTM screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE6Ta.png)

UPDATE 1:
Page: https://www.backtable.com/shows/vi/podcasts/169/fallopian-tube-recanalization

HTML of Wix Audio Player's play button:

```
<div class="MusicPlayer2802357603__playLayout" data- 
hook="playLayout"><button class="PlayPause1336740190__button    
MusicPlayer2802357603__playButton" data-hook="play" aria- 
label="Play" aria-pressed="false" type="button"><svg width="18px" 
height="20px" viewBox="0 0 18 20" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g fill="currentcolor"><path 
d="M17.29,9.02 C18.25,9.56 18.25,10.44 17.29,10.98 L1.74,19.78 
C0.78,20.33 0,19.87 0,18.76 L0,1.24 C0,0.13 0.78,-0.32 1.74,0.22 
L17.29,9.02 Z"></path></g></svg></button></div>
```

When pressed, the aria-pressed goes between false and true. So, my tag is set to fire once per page. I can't figure out the correct trigger though. Thanks!

UPDATE 2:
Attempted to use: button[class^="PlayPause"]
Didn't work and tried a few variations. Did I put something wrong or any other ideas?
[GTM screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDErl.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't use contains with css selectors. You always do match.
2. You don't look at the value of the Element in the debugger. It's misleading to the point of being a bug. Just don't use the preview debugger to see Elements values. Elements are object, not strings and that is a poor attempt of representation the object as a string.
3. Write your own CSS selector for the match clause.

If you have troubles writing the CSS selector, update your question with actual html snippet that you have, indicating what element's clicks you want to capture and we'll write the selector for you.
Here, for your HTML, one of the possible selectors would be this:
`button[class^="PlayPause"]` Here:

[image]

Comment: I updated my original question with the info you requested - thanks.

Comment: Try Any Click that Matches CSS selector: `button[class^="PlayPause"]`

Comment: thanks for the assistance, but unfortunately this did not work. I updated my main question with an update and screenshot.

Comment: is that HTML located in an iframe? I suppose no. Try `button[data-hook="play"]`

Comment: It is not located in an iFrame, but it is Wix... That did not work.

Comment: I see. Well, let's be a bit more brutal then, here: `div[class^="MusicPlayer"] , div[class^="MusicPlayer"] *` This should work, but it's a broad selector check that it only fires on the button. It may fiew on other elements of the player too. I don't have the actual player, so it's hard for me to tell.

Comment: Partially working now. First issue, it fires on both Play & Pause and doesn't differentiate between them. However, I don't see a way to prevent this with the way Wix's audio player is coded. Any solutions? Second issue, this could all be prevented if I could set the tag to only fire on one page. However, when I change the tag setting to this it does not work. It fires the first time correctly and then never fires again, regardless of a page change. So, I have to leave it on "unlimited". I think this is an issue with how Wix handles their websites. Any solutions?

Comment: There are many ways to fix it. Post the HTML of the button when it's play and when it's pause. For the second issue, make a separate question. This becomes way too bloated.